# React useState hook does not seem to update the state on explicitly calling setter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is the code written

```
function App() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const mapper = {
    1: 'One',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three'
  }
  const setFirst = () => {
    setNumber(1);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(mapper[number]);
  }
  const setSecond = () => {
    setNumber(2);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(mapper[number]);
  }
  const setThird = () => {
    setNumber(3);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(mapper[number]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => { setFirst(); }}>One</button>

      <button onClick={() => { setSecond() }} >Two</button>

      <button onClick={() => { setThird(); }} >Three</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expected: 
On click of `setFirst()`, number should be set to 1.
On click of `setSecond()`, number should be set to 2.
On click of `setThird()`, number should be set to 3.

What's happening is

On clicking in sequence 
`setFirst() -> setSecond() -> setThird()`
in repeating fashion

Output:

```
1
One
1
One
2
Two
3
Three
1
One
```

Expected output:

```
1
One
2
Two
3
Three
1
One
2
Two
```

Can someone help me with this. I need help in figuring out where the bug is.

Comment: state update is asynchronous. The state hasnt had the time to update before the console.log

Comment: @Chris console.log() is just for example. If I want to use the value to do something should I do it inside the then() block or in useEffect()

Comment: Use `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

As Chris said in comment, `setNumber` is an asynchronous function, so its update is not visible right after it is performed.

Moreover, you should know that, at each render, each methods inside the component is "stacked" inside its current closure. Let me elaborate:

1. You render the component, which returns the `button` (assume just the first one). When the `button` is rendered, since `setFirst` it's linked to it, you can imagine a sort of room being created, in which all the external variables used inside `setFirst` are copied. Thus, since `setFirst` uses the variables `number` and `mapper`, a copy of them is created inside this "room";
2. When you finally click on `setFirst`, you run `setNumber`. This `setNumber` it does **NOT** update the `number` inside `setFirst` room, but it updates the `number` that will be used in the next render phase;

This example is to make you understand why, when you click on `setSecond`, you get logged *1 One*: when the `setSecond` method was initialized for that render, `number` was still `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I got it. Since `setNumber()` is asynchornous, this is not reflected immediately in `console.log()` even though its in next line. If I call `setFirst()` again after some time, it shows the expected value.

Comment: Yes. Though, I do wonder if, with *after some time*, you mean that you use `setTimeout`: if so, you shouldn't, but you should use `useEffect`.

Comment: I just tried to see if my thought is right with `setTimeout()`. It worked. Then I did this.

`useEffect(() => { console.log(currentPage) }, [currentPage]);`

and it reflected the correct value

Comment: Assuming `currentPage` is `number`, that is the right approach with React Hooks. You should always think ”*cause-effect*”: the *cause* is inside the dependencies array, while the *effect* is the function: you want that *when `currentPage` change, then I do **that***. So, you use `useEffect`, dividing the *cause* from the *effect*.

Answer (score 0):

When setter function in eventloop. there is a asynchronous function. You can let be a `sync` function. but mostly we are not recommanded do this, so i prefer using callback to do this.

```js
setNumber(2, () => {
  console.log('');
})
```

---

Anti-Pattern The sync way

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  setNumber(2);
  console.log(2);
})
```